# jQuery expression as object key

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I need to figure out how to create a dynamic key string for an object. This expression makes JavaScript complain.

```
return {$(this).val(): true};      // returns an object e.g. {2: true}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create the object, then use bracket notation for the dynamic key

```
var obj = {};
var val = $(this).val();

obj[val] = true;

return obj;
```

or a completely unnecessary one-liner

```
return (function(o,e) {o[e.value]=true; return o;})({}, this);
```

Comment: meh. too slow. what adeneo said.

Comment: @AndreasMüller: ditto :P

Comment: Anyway to do this in one line? =)

Comment: @silkfire: `var obj = {}; var val = $(this).val(); obj[val] = true; return obj;` :P (Serious answer: no)

Comment: @silkfire: Not directly in an initializer, no. If you absolutely, positively **must** do it where a single expression is needed, you have to use an inline function: `var obj = (function(val) { var o = {}; o[val] = true; return o;})($(this).val());` Normally, of course, you don't want to do that.

Comment: `return (function(o,e) {o[e.value]=true; return o;})({}, this);`

Comment: Use a function if you want a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript object literal syntax `{x: y}` specifies that `x` will be a (possibly) quoteless string, and `y` any value. You can't use this syntax for dynamic keys.

Use this instead:

```
var foo = {};
foo[$(this).val()] = true;
return foo;
```

Comment: There you go. Got my blooper. Sorry Guys :)